# Android Emulator RAM not extending for Google Play API 27

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-emulator-plugin

When I make create a Virtual Android Device on Android Emulator with Google Play API 27, it does not allow me to give a custom amount of RAM size. Instead it takes a default 1536 MB RAM and 800 MB of Internal Storage. I don't understand why....

[image: This is a Screenshot which shows the options are disabled]

Answer (score 9):

I solved this issue by changing the value in the config file.
In the list of virtual devices (in android studio) click on the arrow on the right side of your device and click on "Show on Disk".

In the folder should be a config.ini file, open it and change `hw.ramSize=1536` to Example: `hw.ramSize=4092`

Answer (score 1):

I expirienced some problems with the Android Virtual Device (loading times) and I started using Genymotion. I suggest you to do so. It is easy to use and full compatible with Android Studio.

Comment: I know about Genymotion, but I want to know how to fix this issue with Android Studio's native Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

As per the update for Oreo 8.1 there might be a restrictions due the feature of Android Oreo (Go edition)

Features in the Android Oreo (Go edition) configuration include:

**Memory optimizations**. Improved memory usage across the platform to ensure that apps can run efficiently on devices with 1GB or less RAM.

**Flexible targeting options**. New hardware feature constants to let you target the distribution of your apps to normal or low-RAM devices through Google Play.

**Google Play**.While all apps will be available on devices running Android Oreo (Go edition), Google Play will give visibility to apps specifically optimized by developers to provide a great experience for billions of people with the building for billions guidelines.

**this might be restricting the emulator to choose the best optimal option to run app on your virtual device**.

Comment: can you please explain how restricting the emulator can lower the load on virtual device?????